# Am I going to have trouble flying with a shortened surname on the ticket?

Tags: passports, tickets

I'm going to Germany from India in 2 days. I have booked Etihad Airways flight but I put P S Narayanan (which is my name) instead of Puthenpurayil Satheeschandran Narayanan as in my passport. Will that be a problem? Do I need to panic?

Comment: Isn't your surname "Narayanan"?  That has not been shortened.

Comment: My surname is Puthenpurayil Satheeschandran, Given Name is Narayanan in passport. But I gave PS Narayanan instead. I shortened my Surname

Comment: So your father is P S something-else?  Is it common to abbreviate surnames like this?

Comment: Yes, In my other ID cards it is PS Narayanan

Comment: Hi again PSN, how is your name shown in the machine readable zone of your passport?  It starts with `P>IND` and then your name.  The "primary identifier" appears first, followed by double `>>`, followed by the "secondary identifier."  In what order do your names appear there, and where is the double `>>`, if anywhere?

Comment: Wait ... do you have a middle name?

Comment: @phoog P<INDPuthenpurayil<Satheeschandran<<Narayana

Comment: @Fattie I don't have a middle name

Comment: @PSN that is correct according to the specification.  The part between the country code and the double `>>` is the primary identifier, normally the family name, and the rest is the secondary identifier, or given name.  Since it seems to be fairly common for people to use initials as you do, you might be fine, especially since you're flying from India. But on the other hand rules about tickets matching ID have been tightening up I'm recent years, and I have no idea what state those rules are in for the flight you'll be taking.

Comment: @phoog Thank you for this. I have contacted Airlines directly and they said name change has to be done (with a fee) and I they already verified my details with my passport and its approved. Thank you so much for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should contact the airline:

> As far as I am aware your first and last name need to be an exact match to that on your passport, I will stand corrected to someone with greater experience though. But think you may need to change the name on your ticket.

(Source: [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g1-i10702-k5337112-Nickname_on_flight_ticket_not_full_name-Air_Travel.html))

Contact details for Etihad Airways are available [here](https://www.etihad.com/en/help/contact-us). Whilst it may be fine, you would want to check just in case.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that a quote from a random post on the Trip Advisor forum is a very useful source.